# Country borders and grids with CountryData plot?

Tags: graphics, curated-data, map

I am coloring several countries in the manner of the following:

```
myc[name_] := If[name == "UnitedStates", Red, Lighter[Gray]] 
Graphics[{myc[#], CountryData[#, {"FullPolygon", "WinkelTripel"}]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

How can I add country borders and longitude-latitude grid, as we could do with WorldPlot?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `EdgeForm` resolves the country borders. Latitude and longitude...well
here is a clumsy way. Depending on your desired grid you may have to clean up conversion.

```
myc[name_] := If[name == "UnitedStates", Red, Lighter[Gray]]
lat = Quiet[
   Line /@ Table[
     Table[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{j, k, 0}], 
        "WinkelTripel"][[1, {1, 2}]], {j, -90, 90, 5}], {k, -170, 170,
       15}]];
long = Quiet[
   Line /@ Table[
     Table[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{k, j, 0}], 
        "WinkelTripel"][[1, {1, 2}]], {j, -170, 170, 15}], {k, -90, 
      90, 10}]];
Graphics[{Gray, lat, long, myc[#], EdgeForm[Black], 
    CountryData[#, {"FullPolygon", "WinkelTripel"}]} & /@ 
  CountryData[]]
```

[image]